# Are there any difference between N and the nominalization of Nする?

Tags: grammar, nominalization

I am still confused with whether or not there is difference between A and B given below.

> A:　結婚に年齢制限がない。There is no age limit for marriage.
>
> B:　結婚することに年齢制限がない。

Are there any difference between N and the nominalization of Nする?

The longer the sentence is, the politer it becomes, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no difference between them except the sentence is longer.

For example, 読書が好き, 読書することが好き, 読書するのが好き are the same meaning.

By the way, I feel 結婚に年齢制限はない is more natural.